# CSCRIPT to autofill from Inputbox

Tags: csv, autofill, wsh

I have a c script file that I need help with.  I want to autofill column B with the employee number from an input box.  If they enter 027, it will autofill column B with that number.
[image]

Comment: Can you post your script?

Comment: THis current script takes a csv file and cleans it up.  It starts out like this: